# How do I find the lat/long that is x km east/west of a given lat/long?

Tags: position, distance, latitude-longitude, idl, idl-programming-language

I have two given lat and lon points.  For example, lets assume I have two positions (point_1 and point_2)  at coordinates (lat1, lon1) and (lat2, lon2). 
I would like to calculate a third point, that is on the same latitude as that of point_2, but  x km to the east or west of point_2.  So the third point will have the same latitude as point_2, but a different longitude depending on distance x (in kilometers), in other words point_3 will be (lat2, lon?).
I am writing this in IDL, but any other language or formulas would be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This problem is solvable with some trigonometrics and basic maths. Sure you can't figure out?

Comment: It is not clear to me what point one has to do with it...?  As per your question, you are just looking for a position x ml west or east of point 2. Is that correct....?

Comment: Is the coordinate in degrees:minutes:seconds or decimal degrees?

Comment: This gentleman has provided all you need as C# code in his blog: http://bryan.reynoldslive.com/post/Latitude2c-Longitude2c-Bearing2c-Cardinal-Direction2c-Distance2c-and-C.aspx

Comment: solutions for this problem are also available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222382/get-lat-long-given-current-point-distance-and-bearing

Answer (score 2):

You don't use point 1 anywhere, do you? Let's say our point is P = (lat, lon)

The first rule of problems like this: draw a picture! From a cross-section of the earth, you can see that the radius of the circle centered on the earth's axis, going through your two points, is `R*cos(lat)`. (`R` is the earth's radius. I hope you don't need to consider the earth an ellipsoid here.) The length `x` therefore takes up an angle (in degrees) of `360*x/(2*pi*R*cos(lat))`. The new point you want is then:

```
P' = ( lat, lon +- 180*x/(2Rcos(lat)) )
```

I'm assuming you're using -180 to 0 for west longitude, so you have +/- for east/west. You'll have to check if you need to wrap around. Pseudo-code:

```
if (lon < -180)
   lon += 360
else if (long > 180)
   lon -= 360
```

Just for fun: if you do care about the earth being ellipsoidal, the radius of the circle is (instead of R*cos(lat)):

```
1/sqrt(tan^2 lat / Rp^2 + 1 / Re^2)
```

where Rp is the polar radius and Re is the equatorial radius. If Rp = Re, this reduces to the original formula, since `1 + tan^2 lat = sec^2 lat`

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

R = 6378.1 #Radius of the Earth
brng = 1.57 #Bearing is 90 degrees converted to radians.
d = 15 #Distance in km

#lat2  52.20444 - the lat result I'm hoping for
#lon2  0.36056 - the long result I'm hoping for.

lat1 = math.radians(52.20472) #Current lat point converted to radians
lon1 = math.radians(0.14056) #Current long point converted to radians

lat2 = math.asin( math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(d/R) +
     math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(brng))

lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(lat1),
             math.cos(d/R)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2))

lat2 = math.degrees(lat2)
lon2 = math.degrees(lon2)

print(lat2)
print(lon2)
```