# Find destination coordinates given starting coordinates, bearing, and distance

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, latitude-longitude

[image]I'm looking at the formula listed here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

I seem to be having trouble as the resulting coordinates are not what I would expect them to be.

Given the following information:

Start lat: 28.455556

Start lon: -80.527778

Bearing: 317.662819(Degrees)

Distance: 130.224835(Nautical miles)

```
def getEndpoint(lat1,lon1,bearing,d):
        R = 6378.1                   #Radius of the Earth
        brng = math.radians(bearing) #convert degrees to radians
        d = d*1.852                  #convert nautical miles to km
        lat2 = math.asin( math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(d/R) + math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(brng))
        lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(lat1),math.cos(d/R)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2))
        return lat2,lon2
```

The function returns:

end lat: -0.209110644042

end lon: -80.5017472335

But this is a coordinate east of my beginning location, it doesn't make any sense because 317 bearing is pointing north-west of my starting location.

Above picture is what It should look like with the final ending coordinate on the upper left.

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: I think lat1 and lon1 need to be in radians. And the result will be in radians.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222382/get-lat-long-given-current-point-distance-and-bearing This should be more exact position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html)

`math.sin(x)`  ... Return the sine of x radians.

So, you need to convert lat1 and lon1 to radians before your equation and then later you can convert lat2 and lon2 back into degrees.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a high precision result, consider using [geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid). Here is an example with GeographicLib, which uses angular units in degrees and distance units in metres.

```
from geographiclib.constants import Constants
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

def getEndpoint(lat1, lon1, bearing, d):
    geod = Geodesic(Constants.WGS84_a, Constants.WGS84_f)
    d = geod.Direct(lat1, lon1, bearing, d * 1852.0)
    return d['lat2'], d['lon2']

print(getEndpoint(28.455556, -80.527778, 317.662819, 130.224835))
# (30.05352669918092, -82.21197985232848)
```

This should be no more than a few nanometres from the exact position.

Answer (score 2):

Doh I had forgot to convert to radians then convert back to degrees when calculation was done. Here is the final code:

```
def getEndpoint(lat1,lon1,bearing,d):
    R = 6371                     #Radius of the Earth
    brng = math.radians(bearing) #convert degrees to radians
    d = d*1.852                  #convert nautical miles to km
    lat1 = math.radians(lat1)    #Current lat point converted to radians
    lon1 = math.radians(lon1)    #Current long point converted to radians
    lat2 = math.asin( math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(d/R) + math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(brng))
    lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(lat1),math.cos(d/R)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2))
    lat2 = math.degrees(lat2)
    lon2 = math.degrees(lon2)
    return lat2,lon2
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that your latitude is just *south* of the equator.  I suspect that your problem is coordinate system: trig functions generally work in Cartesian: the reference angle (bearing 0) is the +x axis, also known as "due east", and progress toward +y (counter-clockwise).  Compass headings start at north and go clockwise.

Replacement 1:

```
brng = math.radians(90-bearing) #convert degrees to radians
```

You've also missed using your starting latitutde.  Try:

```
lat2 = lat1 + math.asin(...
```

This gives us the final location of

```
(28.246445355975514, -80.50284677329569)
```

Comment: Strange according to this formula link, lat2 doesn't seem to add lat1: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/calculate-destination-coordinate/

Comment: So I see ... perhaps my response is incomplete.
I *do* strongly recommend that you trace your intermediate values with print statements to verify the partial results.  Do you *understand* the formula?  That's necessary to making sense of the partial results.

Comment: Yes I understand the formula but python doesn't seem to be able to calculate this. There must me something wrong with the code.

Comment: So what do the partial results tell you about the accuracy with respect to the equations' expectations?