# How to calculate the lat/lng of a point a certain distance away from another using Nodejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to find a square area using a latitude and longitude(x,y) as the following figure

[image]

I need to get all the other 3 corner latitude and longitude by adding 10kms to each side. I am using Node.js/javascript to implement this.

Comment: and this should work anywhere on the globe? i.e. if (x,y) is (90, 0)? or is it simply a case of (10km due east, 10km south) and (10km south, 10km east)

Comment: @JaromandaX first of all i need a simple case to east and to south.

Comment: @S.Serpooshan you're assuming x,y are geometric coordinates rather than degrees of latitude and longitude

Comment: are (x,y) in map coordinates (longitude and latitude) ?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes

Comment: by the way, latitude (north/south) is more like `y` and longitude (east/west) is more like `x`

Comment: @SandipNirmal - that's a big **if**

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the below geometry diagram, the only co-ordinate you need to calculate is - `(x2, y2)` and rest of the two co-ordinate you can calculate using current long, lat - `(x1, y1)` and computed - `(x2, y2)`

[image]

So basically you need a function which will take current lat, long i.e. - `(x1, y1)`, a distance which is `√2 * 10km` in your example and bearing angle to point `(x2, y2)` which at `135` degrees.

```js
let llFromDistance = function(latitude, longitude, distance, bearing) {
  // taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46410871/13549 
  // distance in KM, bearing in degrees

  const R = 6378.1; // Radius of the Earth
  const brng = bearing * Math.PI / 180; // Convert bearing to radian
  let lat = latitude * Math.PI / 180; // Current coords to radians
  let lon = longitude * Math.PI / 180;

  // Do the math magic
  lat = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat) * Math.cos(distance / R) + Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(distance / R) * Math.cos(brng));
  lon += Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(distance / R) * Math.cos(lat), Math.cos(distance / R) - Math.sin(lat) * Math.sin(lat));

  // Coords back to degrees and return
  return [(lat * 180 / Math.PI), (lon * 180 / Math.PI)];

}

console.log(llFromDistance(19.0659115, 72.8574557, Math.sqrt(2)*10, 135))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I've used - not sure of it's usefulness when close to the poles though

```
const fn = (latitude, longitude, distanceInKm, bearingInDegrees) => {
    const R = 6378.1;
    const dr = Math.PI / 180;
    const bearing = bearingInDegrees * dr;
    let lat = latitude * dr;
    let lon = longitude * dr;

    lat = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat) * Math.cos(distanceInKm / R) + Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(distanceInKm / R) * Math.cos(bearing));
    lon += Math.atan2(
        Math.sin(bearing) * Math.sin(distanceInKm / R) * Math.cos(lat), 
        Math.cos(distanceInKm / R) - Math.sin(lat) * Math.sin(lat)
    );
    lat /= dr;
    lon /= dr;
    return {lat, lon};
}
```

so, the points would be

```
fn(y, x, 10, 90), // top right
fn(y, x, 10 * Math.sqrt(2), 135), // bottom right (Pythagoras rules!)
fn(y, x, 10, 180) // bottom left
```