# Get accurate lat/long given current point, distance and bearing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mapbox

Given an existing point in lat/long, distance(inches) and bearing (in degrees converted to radians), I'm trying to calculate the new lat/long. But the resulting is some times inaccurate because I'm trying to measure a small area for the new lat/long. Currently, I'm trying to get the next foot lat/long but some times it has a 1-inch error. I used the following algorithm for this implementation. Referred this thread for the algorithm  [Get lat/long given current point, distance and bearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222382/get-lat-long-given-current-point-distance-and-bearing).

```
public LatLng calculateLatLangFromDistance(double brng, double distance, LatLng latLng){

    double lat1 = Math.toRadians(latLng.getLatitude());
    double long1 = Math.toRadians(latLng.getLongitude());
    double br = Math.toRadians(brng);


   double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(distance/r) +
           Math.cos(lat1)* Math.sin(distance/r)* Math.cos(br));

   double long2 = long1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(br)*Math.sin(distance/r)*Math.cos(lat1),
           Math.cos(distance/r)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));

    lat2 = Math.toDegrees(lat2);
    long2 = Math.toDegrees(long2);

   LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng();
   latLng1.setLongitude(long2);
   latLng1.setLatitude(lat2);

   return latLng1;
}
```

r is defined as 250826771.6535433 // //Radius of the Earth from inches

I'm using the above implementation to generate a 1-foot grid to mapbox map layer but resulting grid's some lines are 1-inch inaccurate. Is there any way to improve this implementation for better results or is there another way to get accurate lat/long for this?[image]

this is the generated grid and I did a line drawing to get the idea about line length of the some lines in the grid.

Comment: Are there still people in this world that calculate in inches?

Comment: You should give an exact example of a calculation. Give the three input values. Then tell wich new point you calculated. And tell what you expected it to be. It is unclear why you use a grid at all.

Comment: @blackapps yes,in our country some clients calculate the distance in inches ..anyway thanks for the reply I managed to reduce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [spherical geometry utilities](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility#spherical) of the Google Maps SDK for Android utility library.

The specific method that you can use will be the **computeOffset** method. You can see it when you search the SphericalUtil in this [link](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/).

*ComputeOffset* returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north). Here are the parameters that you need to specify:

**from** - The LatLng from which to start.
**distance** - The distance to travel.
**heading** - The heading in degrees clockwise from north.

To use this, add the utility library to your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

This is the sample of a line of code that I use:

```
LatLng newCoordinates = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(new LatLng(-25.363, 131.044),30000, 90);
```

Hope this helps!