# Why can't I import geopy.distance.vincenty() on Jupyter Notebook? I installed geopy 2.0.0

Tags: python, import, distance, geopy

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
```

I just installed the `geopy` package 2.0.0, I want to use `geopy.distance.vincenty()` as this [doc](https://kite.com/python/docs/geopy.distance.vincenty) says. However, it returns **ImportError: cannot import name 'vincenty' from 'geopy.distance'**. And if I try

```
from geopy import distance
```

it becomes **AttributeError: module 'geopy.distance' has no attribute 'vincenty'**. About two or three months ago I used this on **Google Colab**, and it was fine. What happened? Could it be the latest version letting go this attribute?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it has been removed. Look at the changelog's [Breaking Changes section](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog_2xx.html#breaking-changes) which contains this entry:

> Removed `geopy.distance.vincenty`, use `geopy.distance.geodesic` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! For a moment I thought it was my installation going south