# How to create a bounding box given in distance, projection, and point to select points given in coordinates?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, pyproj

Given a a point `(lat, lng)` and a projection `crs` create
a bounding box square given by `miles` to select rows
in a geopandas `GeoDataFrame` where the geometry is made up
of other points.

Seems like `pyproject` should do it but I can only find examples
of converting from one projection to another. I want raw coordinates
projected to the current projection. In this case miles would be nice.

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely as shp
#import pyproject ?

def rowsWithinDistanceByPoint(gdf, lat, lng, miles=10, crs='epsg:4269')

    # we do not know to use miles yet so ...
    tenmilesish = 1/6.0 #lame
    circle = shp.geometry.Point(lng, lat).buffer(tenmileish)
    # we really want converted coords
    #(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) = magicFunction(miles, crs)
    # but this sort of gets us there if were not next to the poles
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = circle.bounds

    return gdf.cx[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
```

So this should return the rows that are within 10 miles of the point.

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of searching I found this to be relevant:

[Get lat/long given current point, distance and bearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222382/get-lat-long-given-current-point-distance-and-bearing)

I cannot believe this took half a day to solve!
The red hearing was thinking that the projection mattered. That is taken care of when it was put into a geopandas dataframe.

```
import geopy
#from geopy.distance import VincentyDistance #changed names !!!!!
from geopy.distance import geodesic

def magicFunction(lat, lng, miles):
    # sw, ne
    bearings = [225, 45]
    origin = geopy.Point(lat, lng)
    l = []

    for bearing in bearings:
        destination = geodesic(miles=miles).destination(origin, bearing)
        coords = destination.longitude, destination.latitude
        l.extend(coords)
    # xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
    return l
```

Using those coords to make a `shapely.box` and then plugging it into my existing code:

[image: working code]

Where the blue box is this code and the red oval is what I used in the question.